# meteor rerender login form after log in

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, handlebars.js

I have a Meteor and login form like this:

```
<template name="index">
    <h3>Index Page</h3>
    {{#if currentUser}}
        You are logged in!<br>
        <a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    {{else}} 
        {{> loginForm}}
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="loginForm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="container col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                <h4>Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container col-md-4 sol-sm-4">
                <h4><a href="#"><small>or register</small></a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--div class="row"-->
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="formLogin">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label pull-right">Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label pull-right">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-10 col-sm-6">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Sign in">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!--/div-->
    </div>
    <!-- END loginForm END -->
</template>
```

Here the JavaScript code for template:

```
Template.loginForm.events({
    "submit #formLogin": function(e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log("Form login submitted");
        var loginForm = $(e.currentTarget),
            email = loginForm.find("#inputEmail").val(),
            password = loginForm.find("#inputPassword").val();
        //console.log("Email:" + email + "\n" + "Password:" + password);

        //++++++ Validation
        var trimInput = function(val) {
            return val.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
        };

        isEmailValid = trimInput(email).length > 5 ? true : false
        //console.log(isEmailValid);

        isPasswordValid = password.length > 0 ? true : false
        //console.log(isPasswordValid);
        //------

        if (isEmailValid && isPasswordValid) {
            Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    if (err.message === "User not found [403]") {
                        console.log("User does not exist.");
                    } else if (err.message === "Incorrect password [403]") {
                        console.log("Incorrect password");
                    } else if (err.message === "Match failed [400]") {
                        console.log("Match failed");
                    } else {
                        console.log(err.message)
                    }
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Incorrect data");
        };

    }
});
```

After success login user shouldn't see the form. But if I refresh the page login form appear for 1-1,5 seconds and dissapear. How avoid this?

Comment: Why would you refresh the page? Anyway you can use some css class on your container something like "hidden" from bootstrap and on ```Template['loginForm'].onRendered(function(){ if(!Meteor.userId()){this.$(".container").removeClass("hidden") }})```

Comment: Question is not only in refreshing page, when I open a page I also see login form for one second and after it is disappear. I thought maybe I'm doing somethin wrong. Good idea with CSS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it.

put:

```
    if (Meteor.userId()) Router.go("main");
    return false;
```

after your `Meteor.loginWithPassword` call

ie, for iron router and "main" as the template to render after login

Answer (score 0):

When you do a page refresh the server will log in again as you are creating a new session in effect, it will automatically pick up the fact that you were previously logged in and log you in using those details. However for that period it will not have a userId and currentUser is null. It will however have a loggingIn state of true [Meteor.loggingIn()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loggingin) which you are not checking for. To avoid confusion, check for the loggingin state and then show a loading screen or spinner to indicate something is happening.

You can create a global loggingIn handlebars helper:

```
if (Handlebars) {
    Handlebars.registerHelper('loggingIn', function () {
      return Meteor.loggingIn();
    });
}
```

and then use that to display a loading/spinner template whilst the server is processing the login request after your page refresh:

```
{{#if currentUser}}
    You are logged in!<br>
    <a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
{{else}} 
    {{#if loggingIn}}
        {{> loading}}    
    {{else}}
        {{> loginForm}}
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Which should solve the problem of the app presenting the login screen to the user on first page call/refresh and causing confusion, it will also let them know it is doing something whilst it is working away in the background to log them in.

If you still see the login form it should be really really minimal and flash up very quickly before reverting to either login or loading template.